# Tableau - SAML enable getting vizportal resource not fond

Tags: saml, tableau-api

After enabling SAML-authentication for Tableau Server. We get the below ***resources not found***

```
 vizportal/api/web/v1/getServerSettingsUnauthenticated 404 (Not Found)
vizportal/api/web/v1/getSessionInfo  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```